# How to change background color of a cell based on condition in ngx-datatable?

Tags: angular2-template, background-color, angular-datatables, ngx-datatable

I am using `ngx-datatable`. I want to change background color of any
       particular cell based on value/condition. I am unable to change
       background color for any particular cell. Whatever i am trying its
       changing for entire column.

CSS:

```
.my-custom-cell-notSet {
   background-color: red;
}

.my-custom-cell-yes {
   background-color: rgb(51, 255, 102);
}

.my-custom-cell-no {
   background-color: yellow;
}
```

TS:

```
  rows2 = [
               {
                   sno: "2.1",
                   answers: "Not set",
               }, {
                   sno: "2.2",
                   answers: "Not set",
               }
           ];

       setColorChange(val,RowIndex)
           {
             this.tableColumnListIndex3 = RowIndex;
             this.colorstatus= true;


               if (val === 'Not Set' ) {
                     this.mycolor2 = 'my-custom-cell-notSet';
                   } else if (val === 'No' ) {
                   this.mycolor2 = 'my-custom-cell-yes';
                 } else if (val === 'Yes') {
                         this.mycolor2 = 'my-custom-cell-no';
                 }    }
```

HTML:

```
<ngx-datatable class="material striped ngx-datatable fixed-header
       fullscreen" [rows]="rows2" [columnMode]="'force'" [headerHeight]="50"
               [footerHeight]="100" [rowHeight]="'auto'">
    <ngx-datatable-column
            name="S.NO">
        <ng-template let-column="column" ngx-datatable-header-template>{{column.name | titleCase}} </ng-template>
        <ng-template let-row="row" let-rowIndex="rowIndex" ngx-datatable-cell-template>{{row.sno}}</ng-template>
    </ngx-datatable-column>

    <ngx-datatable-column *ngIf="colorstatus==true && mycolor2=='my-custom-cell-notSet'"
                          name="Answer (y/n)" [cellClass]="mycolor2">
        <ng-template let-column="column" ngx-datatable-header-template>
            {{column.name | titleCase}}</ng-template>
        <ng-template let-row="row" let-rowIndex="rowIndex" ngx-
                     datatable-cell-template>
            <span [hidden]="tableColumnListIndex3==rowIndex&& tableIndex3">
            {{(tableColumnListIndex3 == rowIndex && tableIndex3) ? row.answers : row.answers}}
            </span><select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="row.answers"
                           name="answer3" *ngIf="tableColumnListIndex3==rowIndex && tableIndex3"
                           class="rowInputs"
                           (Change)="setColorChange2(row.answers,rowIndex)">
            <option
                    value='Not Set' translate>Not Set
            </option>
            <option value='Yes' translate>Yes
            </option>
            <option value='No' translate>No</option>
        </select></ng-template>
    </ngx-datatable-column>
</ngx-datatable>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need ng-class for this: there is a nice example in the documentation:
[link](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass)